# Create panel data from merged dataset

Tags: r

I have several merged data frames for baseline and endline data. The variables names are therefore appended with .x and .y for baseline and endline respectively. The data frames were merged by "Name". My data frames look something like this:

```
 Name     v1.x  v2.x v3.x  v1.y  v2.y  v3.y
   a        1     2     5     3    4    6
   b        4     5     3     5    3    5
```

and so on

I want to convert this to panel data so that it looks like this:

```
   Name        v1    v2    v3
    a          1     2     5
    a          3     4     6
    b          4     5     3
    b          5     3     5
```

I have a large amount of data across various merged data frames that I'd like to convert to panel data. How do I go about doing this?

Sample data:

```
    Name        gen_dq_1.1.x        gen_dq_1.1_1.x
      a              2                   0
      b              2 3                 1
      c              2 4                 1
      d              1                   0
      e              1 2 3               1
      f              2 3                 0
      g              1                   0
      h              2 4                 0
      i              1 3                 1
      j              1 2                 1
      k              2 3                 0
      l              3 4                 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Name, names_to = '.value', names_pattern = '(v[0-9])')
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Name     v1    v2    v3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1     2     5
2 a         3     4     6
3 b         4     5     3
4 b         5     3     5
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  Name   v1.x  v2.x  v3.x  v1.y  v2.y  v3.y
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1     2     5     3     4     6
2 b         4     5     3     5     3     5
```

Updated answer:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(!Name, names_to = '.value', names_pattern = '(.*)(?=\\.[xy])')
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  Name     v1    v2    v3 gen_dq_1.1 gen_dq_1.1_1
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
1 a         1     2     5 2                     0
2 a         3     4     6 2                     0
3 b         4     5     3 2 3                   1
4 b         5     3     5 2 3                   1
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 2 x 11
  Name   v1.x  v2.x  v3.x  v1.y  v2.y  v3.y gen_dq_1.1.x gen_dq_1.1.y gen_dq_1.1_1.x gen_dq_1.1_1.y
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                 <dbl>          <dbl>
1 a         1     2     5     3     4     6 2            2                         0              0
2 b         4     5     3     5     3     5 2 3          2 3                       1              1
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Error: Can't subset elements that don't exist.
x Locations 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. don't exist.
ℹ There are only 0 elements.

I should mention that my dataset contains different kinds of variables (dates, names etc.) in addition to numeric values. I was hoping for a way to convert them to long form using the column name suffixes .x and .y

Comment: @Rnovice, The names_pattern in my answer only works for v1,v2,v3.. If you have many more variables with different patterns can you list them?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have around 500 variables in my dataset. I've been playing around with pivot_longer and am now facing an error saying can't combine character to double. I can't possibly list all these in values_transform. 
Is there is simpler way to go about converting this dataset to long form, perhaps a different function I'm unaware of?

Comment: @Rnovice, try: df %>% pivot_longer(!Name, names_to = '.value', names_pattern = '([A-z]+\\d+)')    it should work for everything like Abc12.x etc. Without looking at column names pattern it's difficult to guess all scenarios, but see if this works.

Comment: I'm facing the same error I mentioned above:
Error: Can't combine `gen_dq_1.1.x` <character> and `gen_dq_1.1_1.x` <double>.

Comment: @Rnovice, can you add two columns each those two column patterns to your sample data in your question?

Comment: added the two columns

Comment: @Rnovice, you have tab separated values in gen_dq_1.1.x, do you need to in separate rows or in same rows as they are now?

Comment: @Rnovice, have updated my answer, please check now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now getting the same error (can't combine <double> and <character>) but with two different variables. Would it help to change all variables types to something uniform?
To answer your other question, I need them all in the same rows as they are.

Comment: @Rnovice, Looks like one version is double and other is char. You can change the numeric one to char, then you can pivot_longer. Try: df %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>% pivot_longer(!Name, names_to = '.value', names_pattern = '(.*)(?=\\.[xy])')